# React JS Fetch request fails with 'Cannot POST'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, post, fetch

Im trying to implement a simple fetch request to the server as follows

```
<input type="text" id="usersearchfield" onKeyUp={(e)=>sendData(e.target.value)}/>
```

```
function sendData (input){
    fetch('/api/user/userSearch',{
      method:'POST',
      headers:{'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
      body: JSON.stringify({username: input})
    })
    .then(res =>res.json)
    .then(data =>{
      let input = data.input
      console.log("input is:",input)
    })
  }
```

This is my server's side **index.js**

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true}));

app.use("/api/user" , userRouter);
```

**routes**

```
//serach user
router.post('/userSearch',userController.userSearch)
```

**controller**

```
const userSearch = async (req, res) => {
  const input =req.body.username
  console.log("SERVER GOT",input)
  let search = await User.find({username: {$regex: new RegExp('^'+input+'.*','i')}}).exec()
  search = search.slice(0,10)
  res.send({input:search})
  
  console.log("INPUT IS ",input)
}
```

When i try to execute this code i get `POST http://localhost:3000/api/user/userSearch 404 (Not Found)`
what im missing?

Comment: what is your server url?and ensure the route in server

Comment: its http://localhost:3000/ , if you mean that

Comment: your url was not find,means that not available in your server.

weather check, localhost:3000/api/usersearch  like something

Comment: i understand what you are trying to say. my full url for the controller path is ```/api/user/userSearch``` . i replaced that to my fetch request but i get the same error

Comment: can you remove this and try 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'

Comment: i tried. nothing changed:(